# JS code not executing in iOS web app mode, but fine in iOS safari

Tags: ios, ipad, web-applications, mobile-safari

I have a problem where a web app which is running fine in iOS safari for the iPad, is not working the same when being launched from the iPad home screen as a web-app. The code is exactly the same, cache etc has been flushed, but for some reason a bit of JS which is loading some content just isn't executing in web-app mode, but is running fine in Safari!

Is there anything which could be causing this? Many thanks

Update: what i'm doing is loading a jquery timeline library, using the following initialisation code in the page footer:

```
function checkTimeline() {
        if ($('.flag-content').length > 0) {
            timelineLoaded();
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(checkTimeline, 100);
        }
    }

    checkTimeline();
```

In iOS Safari, this works fine and checks the timeline is loaded before attaching events (via the timelineLoaded() function), but in web-app mode, which I thought was just effectively full screen safari mode, the checkTimeline function never meets the first condition. Baffling!

Comment: On point 1, I've accepted answers whenever possible, if it's been a good answer to the question posted :) I've a few questions which got no replies (not sure if that affects my percentage). Anyway, on point 2 - fair point, shall update question :)

Comment: Apple has blocked most of the java script calls inside UIWebView but the calls work fine in safari. That's why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are using seperate JS file then check whether the Js file is added in the Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources. If not add it manually and try again its working properly.